# How to read and write in file with `fstream` simultaneously in c++?

Tags: c++, file, iostream, fstream

I have the following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    fstream ofile;
    ofile.open("test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    for(string line; getline(ofile, line) ; ) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    ofile << "stackexchnange" << endl;
    ofile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

`test.txt` contains

```
hello world!
stackoverflow
```

Above code outputs

```
hello world!
stackoverflow
```

And after running the code `stackexchange` is not appending at the end of `test.txt`. How to read and then write in file?

Comment: I think, you need to `ofile.clear();` before writing to the file, because once you exit from the loop, the stream is set to badbit or something, which you need to `clear()` before further doing any operation. Well, that is my guess, I'm **not** *sure* though.

Comment: [Why you no check I/O?](http://kayari.org/cxx/yunocheckio.html) If you tested the stream state after doing `ofile << "stackexchnange" << endl;` you would find it failed, telling you something went wrong. If you also test the state _before_ you'll find the stream state is not good even before you try to write anything.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Nice link, although the writing to `std::cerr` in the fixed example is not only redundant (stick to the exception, or `return 1`!) but also missing a terminating semicolon...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, fixed the missing semi-colon, thanks. I didn't bother fixing the redundancy. I agree it could be done better, but I'd rather people check and complain twice than not check at all :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nawaz' comment is correct. Your read loop iterates until the `fstream::operator bool` (of `ofile`) returns false. Therefore, after the loop, either failbit or badbit must have been set. failbit is set when loop tries to read for the final time but only EOF is left to read. This is completely OK, but you must reset the error state flag before trying to use the stream again.

```
// ...
ofile.clear();
ofile << "stackexchnange" << endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

fstream has two positions : input and output.
In your case they both are set to the beginning of the file when you open it.

So you have 4 methods:

```
tellp // returns the output position indicator 
seekp // sets the output position indicator 
tellg // returns the input position indicator
seekg // sets the input position indicator
```

in your case you can use the following line to set output position to the end of the file

```
ofile.seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
```

PS
i missed ios::app flag. mea culpa. comment of @Nawaz gives the right answer: after reading the whole file it is necessary to call

```
ofile.clear(); //cleanup error and eof flags
```

Comment: But it should write  at the beginning of the file. I tried it's not even writing at the file.

Comment: But they opened the stream with `ios::app` mode. So why wouldn't output position seek to the end before a write without doing that explicitly?

Comment: Also, why does the output position being at the beginning not cause the beginning of the file to be overwritten?

Comment: i missed ios::app flag. mea culpa.
comment of @Nawaz gives the right answer: after reading the whole file it is necessary to call ofile.clear();  cleanup error and eof flags