# How to append to a std::fstream after you got to the end (std::fstream::eof() is true)

Tags: c++, file, filesystems, std, fstream

I open a file like this (Because it's part of an exercise and it may require overwriting the file):

```
#include <fstream>            //std::fstream.
std::fstream file("file.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
```

And let's say I have read a file until the end (To get to the end of the file).

```
std::string tmp_buff;
while(std::getline(file, tmp_buff)) {}
file.seekp(file.tellg());
```

Now I have got to the end of the stream, How do I append to the file from here. Because if I just try to write like regularly, it will fail (It will not actually write):

```
file << "Text";
```

The **only** solution I have found is to reopen the file at the end of the file:

```
if(file.eof())
    {
        file.close();
        file.open("file.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
        file << '\n';
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also add `std::ios::app` when opening the stream and use the method `file.clear();` to cleanup error and eof flags after reading the whole file.

For further help, pls read that article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32437476/4183627

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no need to state `std::ios::in` and `std::ios::out` when using a `fstream` because they are there the default value in the constructor. (it is actually `std::ios_base::in/out` to be more exact. `std::ios` (`std::basic_ios<char>`) inherits from `std::ios_base`)
So `std::fstream file(filename)` works the same.

The problem here is how C++ streams work.
When the file is read completely, the `eofbit` is set. After that, another reading happens which will trigger the `failbit` because there is nothing to read and the stream's bool conversion operator returns false and it exits the loop.

The *bits* will stay on until they are cleared. And while they are on, the stream doesn't do anything.
So to clear them:

```cpp
file.clear();
```

Will do the work. You can use the stream after that.